# Persist and object referencing a singleton

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm working on a JPA project. I have an `ExportProfile` object:

```
@Entity
public class ExportProfile{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    private String name;

    private ExtractionType type;

    //...

}
```

`ExtractionType` is an interface implemented by several classes, each for a different *extraction type*, these classes are singletons.
So `type` is a reference to a singleton object. I don't have an `ExtractionType` table in my DB, but i have to persist the *extraction type* of my *export profile*.

How can I persist the `ExportProfile` object using JPA, saving the reference to `type` object?

**NOTE:** The number of `ExtractionType` implementations is not defined, because new implementation can be added anytime. I'm also using Spring, can this help?

Comment: Why do you have to persist the ExtractionType? Cannot you simply use Dependency Injection (e.g. Spring) to inject an implementation of ExtractionType every time you load your Entity from the DB?

Comment: @shuuchan right... in fact i'm using Spring, but how can i "remember" which implementation i have to inject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an idea: make an `ExtractionTypeEnum`, an enumeration with one element for each of the possible singletons that implement `ExtractionType`, and store it as a field in your entity, instead of `ExtractionType` . Later on, if you need to to retrieve the singleton corresponding to a `ExtractionTypeEnum` value, you can implement a factory that returns the correct singleton for each case:

```
public ExtractionType getType(ExportProfile profile) {
    switch (profile.getExtractionTypeEnum()) {
        case ExtractionTypeEnum.TYPE1:
            return ConcreteExtractionType1.getInstance();
        case ExtractionTypeEnum.TYPE2:
            return ConcreteExtractionType2.getInstance();
    }
}
```

In the above, I'm assuming that both `ConcreteExtractionType1` and `ConcreteExtractionType2` implement `ExtractionType`.